# Russian science fiction novella about a giant tower rising from the sea?

Tags: short-stories, story-identification

The story is about a deep sea drilling expedition that drills to an unprecedented depth and encounters an unknown form of matter deep in the Earth. It pushes out the drill bit and continues to extrude out as a giant black tower that almost reaches the ionosphere. The protagonist is a Russian scientist who is attempting to keep it from reaching the ionosphere and basically shorting out the entire planet.

This was most probably written before the 1990's.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"[Черный столб](http://fantlab.ru/work59259)" - Евгений Войскунский, Исай Лукодьянов. ("Black Column" by Eugene Vojskunski, Isaj Lukodyanov).

First [published](http://fantlab.ru/work69611) in 1963.

Please note that there was a movie scenario made (in 2010?) based on this story, called "[Короткое Замыкание](http://roskino.com/scren/boldov_kz.htm)" ("Short Circuit") by Ilya Boldov.

---

> В разодранном устье скважины  показалось  нечто  черное,  закругленное.
>   Черный купол рос, взламывая настил. Вырос  в  полусферу...  Еще  несколько
>   минут - и стало ясно, что внутри вышки поднимается толстый  цилиндрический
>   столб, закругленный сверху.
>
> ... Черный столб уперся верхушкой в  кронблок  вышки.  Со  звоном  лопнули  ее
>   длинные ноги у основания...
>
> Черный столб полз и полз вверх, унося на  себе,  как  детскую  игрушку,
>   стопятидесятиметровую вышку.

---

> At the torn wellhead something black, rounded was showing.  Black dome was growing, breaking the floor. It grew into a hemisphere ... A few minutes later - and it became clear that within the tower rises a thick cylindrical column, with a rounded top.
>
> ... Black tip of the pole pushed into the crown block of the tower. Tower's long legs ruptured at the base with loud ringing noise...
>
> Black pole crawled up, and up, taking with itself, like a child's toy, a 150-meter tower.

Translation is from Google translate - I fixed it up a bit but don't blame me for wanky grammar.

Comment: Any idea if there's an English translation of this book anywhere?

Comment: @TangoOversway - No clue. Being that it's a hacky piece of commie propaganda (I read the first few pages, you don't get more propagandyish than this), I wouldn't be terribly surprised.